# Ajax update fail with Agile Web Development with Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

There are a bunch of questions about this topic (chapter 11) in the book, but none seem to be the same as the one I'm experiencing. I've got the problem that clicking the buy button is not updating the ajax cart in the sidebar - hitting refresh brings it up to date. Looking at the server log I can see that everything appears to be firing correctly -

```
Started POST "/line_items?product_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-08 17:47:36 +0100
Processing by LineItemsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"O+QFilrdqd/AsAoJGHzayWphHT8PDBEBqnjFIAXqQ7Y=", "product_id"=>"1"}
  Cart Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts"  WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  LineItem Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "line_items".* FROM "line_items"  WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ? AND "line_items"."product_id" = 1 LIMIT 1  [["cart_id", 6]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "line_items" SET "quantity" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "line_items"."id" = 10  [["quantity", 7], ["updated_at", "2014-07-08 16:47:36.666376"]]
   (1.5ms)  commit transaction
  LineItem Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items"  WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?  [["cart_id", 6]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered line_items/_line_item.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered carts/_cart.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered line_items/create.js.erb (5.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 7.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

app/views/carts/_cart.html.erb

```
<h2>Your cart<h2>
<table>
  <%= render(cart.line_items) %>

  <tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell"><%= quid(cart.total_price) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>
```

app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
  <td class="item_price"><%= quid(line_item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
```

app/views/line_items/create.js.erb

```
$('#cart').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@cart) %>');
$('#cart').html(alert("alert"));
```

The cart does not update but the alert fires.

Comment: Any errors on browser console?

Comment: Hi @deep - no - console is completely empty.

Comment: Strange! Try to put a simple alert message inside create.js.erb and see if its rendering properly

Comment: Another idea is to change the double quote with a single quote on .html() like $('#cart').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@cart) %>');

Comment: I edited the original post in response -

Comment: @deep seems like good advice as the alert fires.

Comment: In your _cart.html.erb change <%= render(cart.line_items) %> to <%= escape_javascript render(cart.line_items) %>

Comment: Also if this does not resolve the issue try to debug your view partials line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, having followed the rest of @deep's excellent advice to try and diagnose the problem, I followed his final piece of advice and went through every related file line by line, and there it was, in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` - a missing `<div id="cart">` which I must have deleted at some point when editing the file. Lesson learnt - thank you @deep.